# Can WAL replications cause locks?

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-10, wal

Running, under version 10, a setup of 1 master and 3 physcal replicas with their corresponding replication slots.

A stubborn provider that manages our ERP is becoming quite annoying assuring that the cause for some locks that they find when performing certain operations in the master are the replication (WalSenderMain status) threads.

I know that such a thing is not possible, but I haven't found in PostgreSQL documentation, or online, anything saying so. Also, I've found nothing searching about such a thing.

So because you never can now... Is such a thing even possible?

We're telling them that the cause must be long-running queries that are always present when they try to do other things. They blame the replication "because if we restart PostgreSQL we can do it right away"... Precisely! Because then you end those long-running queries. But I'd like to be able to explain that in a more proffesional way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what kind of locks?  Row locks, table locks, Light Weight locks (probably not but you never know), etc.

Comment: You can check the columns `state`, `wait_event` and `wait_event_type`  in the view `pg_stat_activity`  for the sessions that are blocked to find out what they are waiting for.

Comment: Actually yesterday they attached (from their non-admin user) a process list that showed 3 running queries: <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5nnnNtr/thunderbird-tb-DHc4k-J5-Y.png">